# google apps script to get which files that are shared with restricted mode in G drive

Tags: google-apps-script

I am working on a script to get a list of files and folders that are shared with other users in an organization using sharing settings with restricted access [image]

if you can see in the image the area highlighted in yellow, I want a list of files and folders that are shared with this setting.
please let me know if anyone has any idea about it. your help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the files that you have shared with other users and the file is not publicly shared using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet.

And, please set the sheet name to `const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");`.

I thought that in your situation when Drive API is used, the process cost might be able to be reduced. So, this script uses Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  // const checkEmailAddresses = ["###"]; // If you want to retrieve the list by the users, please use this.

  let files = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const obj = Drive.Files.list({fields: "items(id,title,mimeType,shared,permissions(emailAddress)),nextPageToken", q: "'me' in owners and visibility='limited' and trashed=false", maxResults: 1000, pageToken});
    files = files.concat(obj.items);
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  let res = files.filter(({shared}) => shared);
  if (checkEmailAddresses && checkEmailAddresses.length > 0) {
    res = res.filter(({permissions}) => permissions.some(({emailAddress}) => checkEmailAddresses.includes(emailAddress)));
  }
  const values = res.map(({title, id, mimeType}) => [title, id, mimeType]);
  values.unshift(["title", "id", "mimeType"]);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the file list is retrieved by filtering the values you expect and the values are put to the Spreadsheet.
- In order to meet your condition, I used the search query of `'me' in owners and visibility='limited' and trashed=false`. For example, when you want to check the files with other owners, please remove `'me' in owners and`.

  > `visibility`: The visibility level of the file. Valid values are anyoneCanFind, anyoneWithLink, domainCanFind, domainWithLink, and limited. Surround with single quotes '. Escape single quotes in queries with ', such as 'Valentine's Day'.
- About `shared with other users in an organization`, if you want to filter the list by the specific emails of shared users, please use `const checkEmailAddresses = ["###"];`. When this variable is used, you can filter the list by the emails of shared users.

#### References:

- [Search query terms and operators](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-search-terms)
- [Files: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)