# How can I find all files in Google Drive that an email address can access?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a slew of distribution lists and Google Groups. In Google Drive, we have given access to files/folders to these distribution lists and Google Groups.

Is there a way I can find what files/folders in Google Drive these Dls and Google Groups can access?

Comment: If you need an example of impersonation let me know and I'll see if I can update my answer for you :)

Answer (score 2):

I’m assuming that you will be querying files owned by your user, if that’s the case, I highly recommend using the following code that was created by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) as an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69985108/google-apps-script-to-get-which-files-that-are-shared-with-restricted-mode-in-g):

```js
function myFunction() {
   const checkEmailAddresses = ["email@sample.com"]; // email address the files or folders has been shared with

  let files = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const obj = Drive.Files.list({fields: "items(id,title,mimeType,shared,permissions(emailAddress)),nextPageToken", q: "'me' in owners and visibility='limited' and trashed=false", maxResults: 1000, pageToken});
    files = files.concat(obj.items);
    pageToken = obj.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  let res = files.filter(({shared}) => shared);
  if (checkEmailAddresses && checkEmailAddresses.length > 0) {
    res = res.filter(({permissions}) => permissions.some(({emailAddress}) => checkEmailAddresses.includes(emailAddress)));
  }
  const values = res.map(({title, id, mimeType}) => [title, id, mimeType]);
  values.unshift(["title", "id", "mimeType"]);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("1"); //Set the sheet name.
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

The code is printing the file name, ID and metadata type into a spreadsheet, don’t forget to add the [Drive API advance service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services) into your project (the project must be bound to a Google Sheet to work).

If you are working with a business account (aka Google Workspace), and you want to check all files in the organization; you will need to perform [user impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account). The overall logic is the same, but impersonating each user and [list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/list) each of the files owned by them so you can acquire the permissions.

#### References

- [Bound scripts to docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#create_a_bound_script)
- [Returning specific fields for a file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/fields-parameter#format)

Comment: We have millions of files/folders. It will take a while to loop through all of them. I wonder if there is a Drive query filter that would let me do this....